# How can I change the docker jwilder/nginx-proxy upload limits?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, nginx, proxy

In my architecture I use the /jwilder/nginx-proxy as a proxy server in my docker and then I installed 3 WordPress websites with MySQL and WordPress.

They are working well but /jwilder/nginx-proxy has a default configuration upload limit to 2MB but my WordPress template is about 20MB.

When I am trying to upload this template

```
413 Request Entity Too Large
nginx/1.13.6
```

In addition, I used below code to install `/jwilder/nginx-proxy`

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name nginx-proxy  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

How can I configure the upload limits?

Regards

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After searching, I create a file outside the container called `client_max_body_size.conf` with the contents `client_max_body_size 25m;` (or whatever) and bind mount it into your nginx-proxy container:

```
docker run -d --name nginx-proxy -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock \
    -v $ <path>/client_max_body_size.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/client_max_body_size.conf:ro \
    -p 80:80 jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you need to add the following code at the bottom of your .htaccess file.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
php_value post_max_size 128M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

Don’t forget to save your changes and upload the file back to your website.